# Easiest and most complex proof of $\gcd (a,b) \times \operatorname{lcm} (a,b) =ab.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, education

I'm looking for an understandable proof of this theorem, and also a complex one involving beautiful math techniques such as analytic number theory, or something else. I hope you can help me on that. Thank you very much

Comment: This isn't really a deep enough identity to have a complicated proof.

Comment: If you think of numbers as (multi)sets of prime numbers, it's really very obvious. GCD is the (multiset) intersection of $a$ and $b$, LCM is their symmetric difference (xor), and multiplication gives multiset union. Or in simpler terms: GCD is where they overlap, LCM is where they don't, and the $\times$ combines the two. Obviously that'll just give you the union, ie $ab$. This wouldn't really be a proof unless you defined the multi-set analogy rigorously, though (which would be easy but boring).

Comment: @JackM: What do you mean by "symmetric difference (xor) of multisets", or "LCM is where they don't"??

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Sorry, I misspoke. LCM is **not** the symmetric difference of multisets. LCM is actually the smallest multiset containing both $a$ and $b$, which in particular makes it the multiset union of $a$ and $b$ *minus* the multiset intersection of $a$ and $b$. With regular sets that would indeed be the XOR, but with multisets it's a bit (not much) more complicated. The OP's proposition still follows trivially, however.

Comment: @JackM: The smallest multiset containing both $a$ and $b$ is what is usually called the multiset union of $a$ and $b$, which differs from the multiset _sum_ by their multiset intersection. And for regular sets you get the ordinary union, corresponding to (inclusive) OR.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I see. I was pretty much improvising my own terminology, I didn't even think to check the conventional terminology. My bad.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144709/mathrmlcma-b-and-gcda-b.

Comment: @JackM I find it difficult to see how LCM is NOT the symmmetric difference.

Comment: There is a book called "Mathematics Made Difficult" that gives convoluted but technically correct proofs of simple ideas. Some of them are so convoluted that the proof made me laugh out loud.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Let $\gcd(a,b)=d$. Then for some $a_0,b_0$ such that $a_0$ and $b_0$ are relatively prime, we have $a=da_0$ and $b=d b_0$. If we can show that the lcm of $a$ and $b$ is $da_0b_0$, we will be finished.

Certainly $da_0b_0$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$. We must show that it is the **least** common multiple.

Let $m$ be a common multiple of $a$ and $b$. We will show that $da_0b_0$ divides $m$.

Since $m$ is a multiple of $a$, we have $m=ka=ka_0d$ for some $k$. But $b$ divides $m$, so $db_0$ divides $ka_0d$, and therefore $b_0$ divides $ka_0$. Since $a_0$ and $b_0$ are relatively prime, it follows that $b_0$ divides $k$, and we are finished.

Comment: +1. But in the end you used a [version of Euclid's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma#A_generalization_due_to_Gauss), which can be avoided.

Comment: Why are they necessarily relatively prime?

Comment: @DonLarynx:  They meaning $a_0$ and $b_0$? If they are not, then $a$ and $b$ have a common divisor greater than $d$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply  André , however it is not clear to me how that is true. If $d = gcd(a, b)$ then we have $da_0 = a$ and $db_0 = b$. Then, assuming $gcd(a_0, b_0) \neq 1$ and $b_0 \geq a_0$, we have $\exists k \in\Bbb{Z} : b_0 = ka_0$ and thus $da_0 = a, dka_0 = b$. But all that this tells me is that $d$ and $a_0$ are divisors of $a, b$. That means that $d*a_0$ would be the gcd instead of $d$. So is that interpretation correct?

Comment: @DonLarynx: Details depend on how one defines gcd. I am taking the school definition, **biggest** common divisor, though we can adjust the proof if we use the "divides every common divisor" definition. Suppose that $a_0$ and $b_0$ are not relatively prime. Then some $w\gt 1$ divides both of them. Then $dw$ divides both $a$ and $b$, contradicting the fact that $d$ is the gcd of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped.

Comment: @DonLarynx: You are welcome.

Comment: Why does $db_0 | dka_0$ imply that $b_0 | ka_0$?

Comment: By your first divisibility condition, we have $dka_0=qdb_0$ for some $q$. Cancel the $d$. We get ka_0=qb_0$, so $b_0$ divides $ka_0$.

Comment: Would you please explain the last sentence?

Comment: @YaseenMollik $m=k a_0 d$ and if you divide that by $a_0b_0d$ then $a_0,d$ cancel so if $b_0$ divides $k$ then the division gives an integer.

Comment: Implicit in this argument of course is that $d\neq 0$.

Answer (score 37):

First notice that
$$
\dfrac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)} = a\dfrac{b}{\gcd(a,b)} = b\dfrac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}
$$
is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$. By the minimality of the $\operatorname{lcm}$,
$$
\frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}\ge\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\Longrightarrow ab\ge\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\gcd(a,b)\tag{1}
$$
By division, we can write
$$
ab = q\operatorname{lcm}(a,b) + r\quad\text{where}\quad0 \le r \lt \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)
$$
Because $ab$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ are common multiples of $a$ and $b$, so is $r$.  By the minimality of the $\operatorname{lcm}$, $r = 0$.  Therefore, $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ divides $ab$.  Notice that
$$
\frac{ab}{\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)} = \frac{a}{\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)/b} = \frac{b}{\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)/a}
$$
is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$.  By the maximality of the $\gcd$,
$$
\frac{ab}{\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)} \le \gcd(a,b)\Longrightarrow ab\le\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\gcd(a,b)\tag{2}
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get
$$
ab = \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\gcd(a,b)
$$

Comment: very nice and elementary

Comment: @Jonathan: Elementary!? I don't see an elementary but nice formal approach. here  :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I didn't mean "elementary" in any pejorative sense -- just working with simple tools.

Comment: @Jonathan: I took it as a compliment :-)

Comment: Sorry for necrobump this but, I cannot see why $ab/(lcm(a,b)\leq gcd$, the only thing that you proved in (2) is that either $lcm(a,b)/b \leq gcd$, or $lcm(a,b)/a \leq gcd$.

Comment: @user2820579: the maximality of the gcd.

Comment: Could you please explain "By the minimality of the lcm, r=0". Couldn't we just say r = 0, because both a\*b, and lcm(a, b) are multiples of (a, b), therefore lcm(a, b) divides evenly a\*b, leaving 0 remainder?

Comment: Oh nice, it makes sense because r must strictly be less than lcm(a, b) while also being a multiple, meaning it must be 0. I see. However, does my previous comment still hold? Can we not say lcm(a, b) divides a\*b because they are both multiples, and lcm(a, b) <= a\*b?

Comment: @DominicFarolino: multiples of what? $45$ and $75$ are both multiples of $3$ and $5$ and $45\le75$, but $45$ does not divide $75$.

Comment: Was the downvote because there was something wrong with the answer? If so, it would be nice to know what.

Comment: In the first equality two lines above equation (2), why must $\dfrac{ab}{\mathrm{lcm}(a, b)}$ be an integer?

Comment: @Junglemath:  I had tried to show that in the passage above, starting at "By division, we can write" and ending at "Therefore, $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ divides $ab$."

Comment: In my abstract book, lcm(a,b) divides all other multiples is a slightly later result. Correct me if I'm wrong, but a perhaps more elementary method of arriving at (2) for some folks is: Note, lcm(a,b)=a*p and lcm(a,b)=b*q. Since (a,b)=a*s+b*t, we have that (a,b)*lcm(a,b)=a*s*lcm(a,b)+b*t*lcm(a,b)=a*b*q*s+a*b*p*t=a*b(q*s+p*t). It follows that a*b|(a,b)*lcm(a,b). Thus a*b <= (a,b)*lcm(a,b).

Comment: @greycatbird: A proof that $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ divides all other common multiples is provided. The fact that there exist $s$ and $t$ so that $(a,b)=as+bt$ also requires some justification, which probably requires the division algorithm.

Answer (score 15):

The following is more general than for the integers, and therefore simpler (but longer than a proof using unique factorisation without proving it; here we start from scrap).

Let $R$ be an integral domain, where $d=\gcd(a,b)$ is defined to mean that $d\mid a,b$ and $d'\mid a,b\implies d'\mid d$ for all $d'\in R$, while $\def\lcm{\operatorname{lcm}}m=\lcm(a,b)$ is defined to mean that $a,b\mid m$ and $a,b\mid m'\implies m\mid m'$ for all $m'\in R$ (in both cases it is not implied that $\gcd(a,b)$ or $\lcm(a,b)$ always exist, and if they do they are only unique up to multiplication by invertible elements; as a consequence in this setting the equality $\gcd(a,b)\times\lcm(a,b)=ab$ can only be asserted up to such multiplication, or for properly chosen values on the left hand side).

**Lemma.** *Let $r\in R\setminus\{0\}$, and put $D_r=\{\, d\in R: d\mid r\,\}$, the set of divisors of $r$. Then $f_r:d\mapsto r/d$ defines an involution of $D_r$ which is an anti-isomorphism for the divisibility relation: for $a,b\in D_r$ one has $a\mid b\iff f(b)\mid f(a)$.*

*Proof.* Since by definition $d f(d)=r$ for all $d\in D_r$ one has $f(d)\in D_r$ and $f(f(d))=d$. Suppose $a,b\in D_r$ satisfy $a\mid b$, so there exists $c\in R$ with $ac=b$, then $r=bf(b)=acf(b)$ so $f(a)=cf(b)$ and $f(b)\mid f(a)$. Conversly if $f(b)\mid f(a)$ applying this result gives $f(f(a))\mid f(f(b))$ which simplifies to $a\mid b$. QED

**Proposition.** *If $ab\neq0$ and $m=\lcm(a,b)$ exists, then $ab/m=\gcd(a,b)$.*

*Proof.* One has $a,b\mid ab$ so $m\mid ab$ by definition of the $\lcm$; therefore $a,b,m\in D_{ab}$. One has $f_{ab}(a)=b$ and $f_{ab}(b)=a$, and since $a,b\mid m$ one has $f_{ab}(m)\mid b,a$ by the lemma. Also if $d'\in R$ satisfies $d'\mid a,b$ then $d'\in D_{ab}$ so $b,a\mid f_{ab}(d')$ by the lemma, whence $m\mid f_{ab}(d')$ by definition of the $\lcm$, and once again by the lemma $d'\mid f_{ab}(m)$. Thus $$ab/m=f_{ab}(m)=\gcd(a,b). \qquad\text{QED}$$

Concluding $\gcd(a,b)\times \lcm(a,b)=ab$ needs the precaution that it only holds if $\lcm(a,b)$ exists, and then the left hand side is defined up to invertible factors only, so the equality should be interpreted in this sense. For the case $ab=0$  not covered by the proposition one has $0=\lcm(a,b)$ and $\{a,b\}=\{0,\gcd(a,b)\}$, so the equality holds without any difficulty.

Note that the existence of $\gcd(a,b)$ *does not imply* the existence of $\lcm(a,b)$ in general.

Comment: Readers can find another involution-based proof in [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/363030/242)

Comment: Dear Marc! Let me ask you the following question: If $ab=0$ then at least one of them is zero since we are in Integral Domain, i.e. $a=0$ or $b=0$. How it follows that $\text{lcm}(a,b)=0$? Suppose that $a=0$ then $\text{lcm}(a,b)=\text{lcm}(0,b)$ but the last term is meaningless.

Comment: @ZFR The _only_ multiple of $0$ is $0$ itself, which is also a multiple of any other element of $R$. So even without pondering on the meaning of "least" here, it stands to reason that $\operatorname{lcm}(0,b)=0$ for any $b$, and indeed that is how it is defined whenever one wants $\operatorname{lcm}$ to be defined for all elements (and for completeness, $\gcd(0,b)=b$ for any $b$). And by "the equation" I refer to the one of the title of the OP question.

Answer (score 13):

Let's prime factorize  a and b.Let $a=p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}\cdots\cdot q$ and $b=p_1^{y_1}p_2^{y_2}\cdots r$ where  $p_i$'s are distinct primes and GCD$(r,q)=1$
Then

GCD$(a,b)=p_1^{\min(x_1,y_1)}p_2^{\min (x_2,y_2)} \cdots$

LCM$(a,b)= qrp_1^{\max(x_1,y_1)}p_2^{\max(x_2,y_2)}\cdots$

Then since $\min(x, y) + \max(x, y) = x+y$, we have
LCM$(a,b)$GCD$(a,b)=ab$

Comment: I believe this proof is correct, but can you please explain the need for defining $q$ and $r$? Are they not like any other prime factor?

Comment: same question can you explain what is $q$ and $r$ more preciselly?

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a simple one:

By definition, a least common multiple of a pair of integers $a$ and $b$ is an integer $m$ such that $a|m$, $b|m$, and $m$ divides every common multiple of $a$ and $b$.

Just look that if $c$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$, we have that $c=ax=by$ for some integers $x$ and $y$.

Then $\frac{a}{(a,b)}x=\frac{b}{(a,b)}y$, and because $\left(\frac{a}{(a,b)},\frac{b}{(a,b)}\right)=1$, we have that $\frac{a}{(a,b)}$ divides $y$.

So $y=\frac{a}{(a,b)}n$ for some integer $n$ and $c=\frac{ba}{(a,b)}n$.
This shows that every time you have a common multiple of $a$ and $b$ it can be divisible by $\frac{ba}{(a,b)}$, then $[a,b]=\frac{ba}{(a,b)}$.

Answer (score 5):

The following simple duality-based proof works in any integral domain.

**Theorem**  $\rm\quad gcd(a,b)\, =\, ab/lcm(a,b)\ \ $  if $\ \ \rm lcm(a,b) \;$  exists, and $\rm\ ab\ne 0$

**Proof**  $\rm\quad d\mid a,b\!\color{#c00}\iff\! a,b\mid ab/d \!\iff\! lcm(a,b)\mid ab/d \color{#c00}\iff d\mid ab/lcm(a,b)$

**Remark** $\ $ The red equivalences are  $\rm\:x\mid y\color{#c00}\iff y'\mid x'\:$ for $\rm\ x'\! = ab/x\ $ being reflection on the divisors of $\rm\:ab,\:$ highlighting the $\rm\ gcd = lcm' \ $ duality, namely

$$\rm gcd(a,b)\, =\, \frac{ab}{lcm(b,a)}\, =\, lcm(a',b)'\qquad\quad  $$

[See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/363030/242) for a proof emphasizing this reflection (involution) and the innate duality.

Comment: The middle equivalence is true, but $a,b\mid c\Rightarrow\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)\mid c$ almost feels like we're assuming something we are trying to show. It may be that things are so basic at this level, that I am not sure what we can assume.

Comment: @robjohn It is not circular. The hypothesis that $\rm\ lcm(a,b)\ $ exists means, by *definition*, that $\rm\ a,b\mid x\iff lcm(a,b)\mid x.\:$ Dually, $\rm\ x\mid a,b \iff x\mid gcd(a,b),\:$ if said gcd exists. These are the [universal definitions of lcm,gcd](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/23500) used in general domains, where least/greatest means wrt divisibility. They're equivalent to the well-known definitions in Euclidean domains, where least/greatest means wrt Euclidean value ("size"), e.g. $\rm\:|x|\:$ in $\rm\:\Bbb Z,\:$ and $\rm\:deg(f(x))\:$ in $\rm\:F[x].$

Comment: My impression was that $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$ is the least positive number that is a multiple of both $a$ and $b$. That it divides all other common multiples of $a$ and $b$ is not immediately obvious. This is why I felt it necessary to prove that $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)\mid ab$ in my answer.

Comment: @robjohn The division algorithm yields a [one-line proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/322153/23500) that in $\rm\,\Bbb Z\,$ a common multiple is least in value iff it is divisibly least (i.e. divides all common multiples). Similarly in other Euclidean domains, as I said above.

Comment: Yes, that is essentially the proof that I used. However, I assume that the person asking a basic question would be dealing in $\mathbb{Z}$, and have little familiarity with other Euclidean domains. This is the basis of my earlier discomfort. In any case, I see where you are coming from. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know that you are familiar to the Group theory, but if you consider groups $\mathbb Z_a$ and $\mathbb Z_b$ then the following homomorphism can do what you are looking for. I mean: $$\phi: \mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z_a\times\mathbb Z_b,~~~~n\mapsto(n|_{\text{mod}~a},n|_{\text{mod}~b})$$

Comment: I can see that the LCM generates the kernel of this homomorphism, but would you please explain where the GCD comes in? It should be the index of the image in the codomain, but is this so obvious?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Honestly, at the first view, No. You are right. In fact the OP should use the first theorem of homomorphism and find the kernel and the image of the map. However, the OP preferred the answer via number theory approach.

Answer (score 4):

**Brute Force Approach**
We can write $a$ and $b$ in the following manner:
$$a=d x_0,\;b=d y_0$$
$$m=a p_0=b q_0$$
Here $d=gcd(a,b)$ and $m=lcm(a,b)$. And both $\{x_0,y_0\}$ and $\{p_0,q_0\}$ are sets of co-prime numbers.

By multiplication, we can write:
$$ab=d^2x_0y_0$$
$$ab\cdot p_0 q_0=m^2$$
Multiplying both equations:
$$(ab)^2\cdot p_0q_0=(md)^2 \cdot x_0y_0$$
Now we only need to prove that $p_0q_0=x_0y_0$, in fact we can prove that $x_0=q_0$ and $y_0=p_0$.

Using the first two equations:
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{x_0}{y_0}=\frac{q_0}{p_0}$$
Because $\{x_0,y_0\}$ and $\{p_0,q_0\}$ are sets of co-prime numbers, both $\frac{x_0}{y_0}$ and $\frac{q_0}{p_0}$ are the simplest or irreducible fractions of $\frac{a}{b}$. Hence both the numerators and denominators are equal i.e. $x_0=q_0$ and $y_0=p_0$.
$$\require{cancel} (ab)^2\cdot \cancel{p_0q_0}=(md)^2 \cdot \cancel{x_0y_0}$$
$$(ab)^2=(md)^2 \Rightarrow ab=md$$

---

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2):

Easy proof:

$$[p,q] = p*q, \space if \space (p, q) = 1$$ [p, q] = lcm(p, q) and (p, q)=gcd(p, q). This can be proved using only simple property of relatively prime numbers.

Another fact: $$ [mp, mq] = m[p, q] \space  if \space m\in N $$ Since common multiple is all about dividable relation, multiply everything by m won't change that.  
let $(p, q) = d, so \space (p/d,q/d)=1$
$$ (p,q)[p,q] = d*d*[p/d,q/d]=d*d*\frac{p}{d}*\frac{q}{d}=pq $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\ell= \text{lcm}(a,b), g=\text{gcd}(a,b)$ for some $a,b$ positive integers.


Division algorithm: exists $q,r$ integers with $0\leq r < \ell$ such $ab = q\ell + r$. Observing that both $a$ and $b$ divide both $ab$ and $q\ell$ we conclude they both divide $r$. As $r$ is a common multiple, we must have $\ell \leq r$ or $r\leq 0$ so $r=0$.


Therefore $s=\frac{ab}{\ell}$ is an integer. Observe that $\frac{a}{s}=\frac{\ell}{b}$ and $\frac{b}{s}=\frac{\ell}{a}$ are both integers, so $s$ is a common divisor. Thus $g\geq s = \frac{ab}{\ell}$.


On the other hand, $\frac{ab}{g}=a\frac{b}{g}=b\frac{a}{g}$ where $\frac{b}{g}$ and $\frac{a}{g}$ are both integers, so $\frac{ab}{g}$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$. As $\frac{ab}{g}>0$ we conclude $\frac{ab}{g}\geq \ell$, therefoire $\frac{ab}{\ell}\geq g$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the easiest proof but here an other solution using the Gauss lemma.

1-
$GCD(a;b)=d \Rightarrow a=dx, b=dy$ with $x,y,d \in \mathbb{N}$ and $GCD(x;y)=1$
More over we can writte$\frac{ab}{d}=ay=bx$ so it cames that the integer $ay=bx$ is a commom multiple of $a$ and $b$ by definition.

2-
Now let note $m=LCM(a;b) \Rightarrow  \exists k,l \in \mathbb{N} $ s.t. $ m = ak = bl \Rightarrow \frac{m}{d}=\frac{xdk}{d}=\frac{ydl}{d}=xk=yl \in \mathbb{N}$

3-
*Reminder: Gauss lemma:* If $a,b,c$ are three integers such that $a$ and $b$ are coprime and $a$ divides $bc$ then $a$ divises $c$.
We take $x,y$ two coprime integers and $l$. As we wrotte above $xk=yl \Rightarrow \frac{yl}{x}=k \in \mathbb{N}$ so $x$ divides $yl=\frac{m}{d}$. Hence by the Gauss lemma we get that $x$ divides $l$. Equivalently we get by the same justification that $y$ divides $k$.
So we can writte: $m=bl=dyl=dyxl'$ with $l=xl'$ and on the other side $m=ak=dxk=dxyk'$ with $k=xk'$

4-
From "-3" we got that $dyxl'= m = dxyk'\Rightarrow l'=k'$. But $m$ is by def the smallest commom multiplier so  $l'=1=k'$ and we get that $LCM(a;b)=dxy$.
*Rem:* Indeed $dxy$ is all ready by def a commom multiplier of $a$ and $b$ because $dxy$ is all ready a multiple of $a$ and $b$ as it is divisible by them!

5-
So: $GCD(a;b)LCM(a;b)=ddxy=d^2xy$ while $ab=dxdy=d^2xy$
Q.E.D.

Answer (score -1):

Easy proof by set theory: (I'm a beginner and thought of this, please correct if me if I'm wrong)

Let $a=xy, b=xz$.

So
$a = \{x,y\}$ and $b = \{x, y\}$,

where $x$ is the product of the common prime factors of $a, b$ which is $\gcd(a,b)$ and the product $xyz$ produces $\text{lcm}(a,b)$

By Set Theory,

$P(a \cup b) \cdot P(a \cap b) = P(a) \cdot P(b)$.

$xyz \cdot x = xy \cdot xz$

lcm(a,b) * gcd(a,b) = ab

Comment: Please note that "set theory" is a whole different subject that has nothing to do with this