# Factorization in $F[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f(x), g(x), h(x)$ be elements of  $F[x]$, where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are relatively prime. If $f(x) \mid h(x)$ and $g(x)\mid h(x)$ prove that $f(x)g(x)\mid h(x)$.

Here $F$ is a field.

This is a practice question I need to know for my finals.

Comment: What exactly is F(x)?

Comment: @silencer F(x) is a field

Comment: @KjTada : You're omitting context.  You must have seen this question posed in a context in which it was stated that $f(x)$, $g(x)$, and $h(x)$ are polynomials, or whatever it is that they are, and that $F$ is a field, or whatever it was intended to be.  You omitted that information.

Comment: @YACP found the error.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes f(x),g(x), h(x) are polynomials. F is a field.

Comment: Then $F[x]$ is an euclidean domain, so what you state follows. The proof of this fact is almost line by line the same as for integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That $\rm\:gcd(f,g) = 1\:\Rightarrow\:lcm(f,g) = fg\:$ can be proved the same as for integers, namely:

Here is a proof of $\rm\ f,g\,|\,h\:\Rightarrow\:fg\,|\,hd,\ \ d = gcd(f,g)\, [= af+bg\ $ by Bezout]

$\rm\begin{eqnarray} 
\rm\quad f,g\mid h\, &\Rightarrow&\,\rm fg\mid hf,hg &\Rightarrow&\,\rm fg\mid ahf\, +\, bhg \ =\ h(af\!+\!bg)\, = hd\quad [Bezout\ form] \\
\rm\quad f,g\mid h\, &\Rightarrow&\,\rm fg\mid hf,hg &\Rightarrow&\,\rm fg\ |\ \gcd(hf, hg)\, =\: h \gcd(f,g) = hd\quad [GCD\ form] \\
\end{eqnarray}$

**Remark** $\ \ $ [More generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/350465/23500) $\rm\ \ gcd(f,g)\, lcm(f,g) = fg,\ $ in any domain where the lcm exists

**Theorem**  $\rm\quad gcd(a,b)\, =\, ab/lcm(a,b)\ \ $  if $\ \ \rm lcm(a,b) \;$  exists, and $\rm\ ab\ne 0$

**Proof**  $\rm\quad d\mid a,b\!\iff\! a,b\mid ab/d \!\iff\! lcm(a,b)\mid ab/d \iff d\mid ab/lcm(a,b)$

Answer (score 1):

We are working in a some polynomial, which is a UFD, so we can use Euclid's lemma. To say that $f\mid h$ and $g\mid h$ is to say that there exist elements $f',g'$ such that $h = ff'$,$h=gg'$, so that $ff' = gg'$. Now $f,g$ are coprime, so that $g\mid f'$; thus there exists $k$ such that $f' = gk$ (this is where we apply Euclid's lemma), and we have $h = fgk$, as required.

Comment: I really like your explanation and it seems like it extends to polynomials as f(x),g(x) and h(x) in my question were polynomials. Could you explain how you concluded this " $f,g$ are coprime, so that $g∣f'$ ′"

Comment: That is not a valid proof.

Comment: @mathGems, what would be a correct proof in this instance. I am just finding your proof a little hard to grasp. This question is from a first course in Abstract Algebra

Comment: @MathGems I just saw your edit, reading it now. Thankyou

Comment: @MathGems Mind explaining the non-validity of my proof?

Comment: @Silencer The proof does not invoke any special properties of the ring $\,F[x].\:$ So if the proof were valid, it would be true in any ring. But the result is not true in any ring. Probably you are implicitly assuming some properties of $\,R = F[x].\,$ Perhaps you assume $\,R\,$ is a UFD? Or perhaps you are assuming Euclid's Lemma? (a consequence of $\,R\,$ being a Euclidean domain). One can only guess, since the proof gives no justification for the key claim $\,g\mid f'$ (which, in fact, is *equivalent* to the sought result).

Comment: @KjTada What results do you know about $\,F[x]\,?$ Do you know it has a division and Euclidean algorithm for the gcd? Euclid's Lemma? Bezout's identity for the gcd? That $\,F[x]\,$ is a UFD (unique factorization domain)?

Comment: @MathGems Yes, I was implicitly using the fact that we were working in a polynomial ring (and using Euclid's lemma!), despite my (misleading) early claim of working in some general ring. Sorry for the confusion.