# Proving there are $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{\text{lcm}(a,b)}\right\rfloor$ numbers divisible by a and b in [1,n]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove the following (Please let me know if it isn't actually true):

Consider the range $[1,n]$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Consider $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.Prove that, in this range, there are $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{\text{lcm}(a,b)}\right\rfloor$ numbers that are divisible by both $a$ and $b$.

I have the intuition for this. E,g, let a=2, b=5 and n=200. Being divisible by 2 and 5 implies being divisible by 10, and 201 = 20*10 + 1 thus there are 20 numbers divisible by both 2 and 5.

However, I am not able to formulate a proof.

One of the first issues was when I was attempting to prove $a|x \cap b|x \implies \text{lcm}(a,b)|x$. I'd start with

$a|x \iff x = ac$ and $b|x \iff x = bd$ thus we have $x = ac = bd$ but not be sure where to continute. I know that $\text{lcm}(a,b) = \frac{ab}{\text{hcf}(a,b)}$ and think I need to apply this at some point but not sure how. Would this be easier to prove with the restriction that a,b are coprime?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Two main steps to the proof... first prove that every number divisible by both $a$ and $b$ is divisible by $\text{lcm}(a,b)$.  Next, prove that the number of numbers in the range $[1,n]$ who are divisible by $x$ is equal to $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{x}\right\rfloor$.  The result follows.

Comment: Thank you. I am struggling with the first part, with my working included in the post.

Comment: [Proving that any common multiple of two numbers is a multiple of their least common multiple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878639/proving-that-any-common-multiple-of-two-numbers-is-a-multiple-of-their-least-com).  Also related to this fact but in the other direction: [Concise proof that every common divisor divides gcd without bezouts identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362975/concise-proof-that-every-common-divisor-divides-gcd-without-bezouts-identity?noredirect=1&lq=1)