# The relation of LCM and GCD in Euclidean rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Given two elements $a,b$ in the Euclidean ring $R$ their *least common miltiple* $c\in R$ is an element in $R$ such that $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$ and such that whenever $a\mid x$ and $b\mid x$ then $c\mid x$.

a) Prove that any two elements in the Euclidean ring $R$ have a least common multiple in $R$.

b) If the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$ is denoted by $[a,b]$, prove that $[a,b]=ab/(a,b).$

**Proof:**

(a) Consider the ideals $(a)$ and $(b)$, where $(x)=xR$. Their intersection $(a)\cap (b)$ is also ideal of $R$ since Euclidean ring is the ring of principle ideal then $(a)\cap (b)=(c)$ for some $c\in R$. I proved that this $c$ has all needed properties of least common multiple. Thus the LCM of $a$ and $b$ exists.

(b) We know that $\text{gcd}(a,b)$ exists in Euclidean ring for any $a,b\neq 0 \in R$. But I have no thoughts how to prove that $[a,b]=ab/(a,b)$.

So I would be very thankful answer.

Comment: Several thoughts are available in pre-existing questions. Indeed, searching around a bit yields [complete answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/29335).  You might also experiment with the search assist tool https://approach0.xyz

Comment: It doesn’t have so much to do with euclideanness as with unique factorization in $R$.

Comment: @rschwieb, but the reasoning on the link which you have provided is very short and unclear. That's why I am asking.

Comment: @RFZ If you are unclear about something you read there (or any of the other explanations) you should try commenting on those first, rather than making duplicate content. In fact, [at this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/363030/29335) Bill Dubuque has crosslinked to no less than three of his other answers on the same topic.