# Confusion with divisibility symbol in ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $a\in R$ and $b\in R-\{0\}$ we say that $b$ divides $a$ (notation: $b\mid a$) if $\exists t\in R$ such that $a=bt$.

In my book I often see the symbol $\dfrac{a}{b}$ and it confuses since it looks like usual division. But I guess that $\dfrac{a}{b}$ is the same as $t$. However, I think that the notation $\dfrac{a}{b}$ is informal. Am I right?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which book are you referring to?

Comment: a/b _is_ usual division.

Comment: @quasi, Herstein's book "Topics in algebra"

Comment: Herstein does _not_ use $a/b$ to mean $a|b$. the notation $a/b$ refers to fraction. The notation $a|b$ is a statement asserting that $b$ is a multiple of $a$. See rschwieb's answer.

Comment: @quasi, I am just aksing what does $\frac{a}{b}$ mean? For example, what is the following symbol $c=\frac{a}{b}$?

Comment: It means a fraction (the result of division). $c=a/b$ means $a=bc$, whereas $b|a$ means $a=bc$, for _some_ $c$. Note the expression $a/b$ represents a calculation, where as $b|a$ is a statement which is either true or false.

Comment: @RFZ Just read existing solutions and ask questions if you have to. I’m not going to repeat content like that. Start here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/349858/29335

Answer (score 3):

The symbols $\frac ab$ and $a|b$ are completely different things.

The first one usually denotes the equivalence class of pairs equivalent to the pair $(a,b)$ via the relation $(a,b)\sim (c,d) \iff ad=cb$. This is the same thing as $ab^{-1}$ and also $a/b$. In a nutshell, we are talking about "the result of $a$ divided by $b$" here.

The notation $a|b$ denotes that $a$ and $b$ are related by divisibility, i.e. that $ar=b$ for some suitable $r$. This doesn't produce any "result" like the last one: it just is a statement about how $a$ and $b$ are related.

Comment: For example, I need to show that $\text{gcd}(a,b)=\dfrac{ab}{\text{lcm}(a,b)}$. Is it the same thing as $ab=\text{lcm}(a,b)\text{gcd}(a,b)$?

Comment: @RFZ Yes, those two equalities mean the same thing.

Comment: How does the equivalence relation here refer? We do not use it in the symbol $(a,b)=\dfrac{ab}{[a,b]}$

Comment: Not really.  The first claims more.  It usually claims that lcm(a,b) is invertible in the ring.  Even if not, It surely claims that gcd(a,b) is unique such that the second equality holds.

Comment: @RFZ I don't understand what you are asking in the last comment. Maybe this will help: if $a,x,b$ are nonzero elements in a field,  and $a=bx$, you can say, simultaneously, that $x=\frac ab$, $b=\frac ax$ and $b|a$ and $x|a$.

Comment: @rschwieb, Regarding your last comment, I know these facts are true for equation in the field. For example, I need to prove that $(a,b)=\frac{ab}{[a,b]}$ for $a,b\in R-\{0\}$, where $R$ is euclidean ring. How to prove it? As you said the RHS, namely the fraction $\frac{ab}{[a,b]}$ is the equivalence class, which consists of pairs $(c,d)$ such that $\frac{ab}{[a,b]}\sim \frac{c}{d}$ (in other words, $(ab)d=c[a,b]$). However, the LHS is just $(a,b)$ which is an element of euclidean ring $R$. So we need to prove that element is equal to the equivalence class?

Comment: But it sounds very weird and wrong. Could you clarify my thoughts, please.