# Alternative proof of $\gcd(a,b)\mid\text{lcm}(a,b)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I proved this problem using the theorem $\gcd(a,b)\text{lcm}(a,b)=ab$ Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$. Then $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$. Thus, $a=dr$ and $b=ds$ for some integer $r$ and $s$. Then
$$d(\text{lcm}(a,b))=ab\Rightarrow \text{lcm}(a,b)=\frac{ab}{d}\Rightarrow \text{lcm}(a,b)=\frac{d^2rs}{d}\Rightarrow \text{lcm}(a,b)=drs\Rightarrow d\mid \text{lcm}(a,b)$$
as required.

Is my alternative proof for this problem correct?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349858/easiest-and-most-complex-proof-of-gcd-a-b-times-operatornamelcm-a-b-a

Answer (score 1):

Your alternate proof is correct, but you don't need to do all this, you can directly say d|a and a|lcm(a,b).

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, I do know this proof. I am just worried my proof might reach to circular reasoning so I want to verify at here. Thanks anyway.

Comment: he literally says "alternate proof", so the second part of your answer seems pointless

Answer (score -1):

$\gcd(a,b)\cdot\text{lcm}(a,b)=a\cdot b=>$
$$
\\\frac{\text{lcm}(a,b)}{\gcd(a,b)}=\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}\cdot\frac{b}{\gcd(a, b)}\in\mathbb N
$$