# Find numbers $x$, $y$ such than $(x,y) = 18$ and $[x,y]= 3780$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Where $(,)$ is the greater common divisor and $[,]$ the smallest common multiple.

In general how do you solve this kind of problems?

Comment: $xy=(x,y)\cdot[x,y]$

Comment: *Hint* $$(x,y)\cdot[x,y]=x\cdot y\implies x\cdot y=68040$$ There is a nice explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349858/easiest-and-most-complex-proof-of-gcd-a-b-times-operatornamelcm-a-b-a)

Comment: Does this work for you: $x=18, y=3780$ ?

Comment: Thanks everybody. I understand it.