# My approach in proving $\gcd(a,b)\operatorname{lcm}(a,b) = ab$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349858/easiest-and-most-complex-proof-of-gcd-a-b-times-operatornamelcm-a-b-a) and its answers. There are some nice answers but I was wondering if my original approach could be solved.

My approach:
Let's assume $m$ is $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ and $d$ is $\gcd(a,b)$ and $m = aq$, $m = br$
We know, $d = ax + by$
 So, $\gcd(a,b) \operatorname{lcm}(a,b) = md $
       $= m(ax + by) $
$ = (br) ax + (aq) by = ab(rx + qy) $

Is there any way to prove $rx + qy = 1$? I know $x,y$ are relatively prime, so are $q,r$ but couldn't prove this using this information.

Comment: Just note that the fact that $(x,y)=1$ and $(q,r)=1$ is not enough by itself to show $rx + qy = 1$ (easy counterexamples $x=y=q=r=1$ or $(x,y)=(1,2)$, $(q,r)=(1,-2)$ to include negative numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: by your definition of $m$, we immediately conclude that $\gcd(q,r)=1$, and then you stated that there exists integers $x,y$ such that $d=ax+by$, so when you divide by $\gcd(a,b)$ you get $rx+qy=1$ and we know there exists such $x,y$ because $\gcd(q,r)=1$

Long answer/explanation: let's just make our convensions clear and try to prove it your approach:

Let $a=da_1$ and $b=db_1$ where $\gcd(a_1,b_1)=1$ and $\gcd(a,b)=d$ for some integers $d,a_1,b_1$.

Now ${\rm lcm}(a,b)=da_1b_1$ by definition. So, we can say if $m={\rm lcm}(a,b)=aq=br$, we have $q=b_1$ and $r=a_1$, so we can exchange $q,r$ this way. We know that there exists integers $x,y$ such that 
$$d=ax+by$$
But we can choose initial solutions $x_1$ and $y_1$ such that 
$$d=ax_1+by_1=da_1x_1+db_1y_1 \iff 1=a_1x_1 +b_1y_1$$
which deduces what you desired.