# why it will be finished when we take lcm of $a$ and $b$ = $da_0b_0?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm posting this doubt since  this user  is  not active for many years

Let  and  be positive integers, show that $\gcd(, ) \cdot \mathrm{lcm}(, ) = b$

My attempt : I found the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/349891/557708) but I'm not getting this answer in my mind.

User answer given :

Let $\gcd(a,b)=d$. Then for some $a_0,b_0$ such that $a_0$ and $b_0$ are relatively prime, we have $a=da_0$ and $b=d b_0$. If we can show that the lcm of $a$ and $b$ is $da_0b_0$, we will be finished.

Certainly $da_0b_0$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$. We must show that it is the **least** common multiple.

Let $m$ be a common multiple of $a$ and $b$. We will show that $da_0b_0$ divides $m$.

Since $m$ is a multiple of $a$, we have $m=ka=ka_0d$ for some $k$. But $b$ divides $m$, so $db_0$ divides $ka_0d$, and therefore $b_0$ divides $ka_0$. Since $a_0$ and $b_0$ are relatively prime, it follows that $b_0$ divides $k$, and we are finished.

**My doubt** : user is saying if we can show that the lcm of $a$ and $b$ is $da_0b_0$, we will be finished.

My question is  that how it   can be finished?  Suppose if I take $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b) = da_0b_0 = \gcd(a,b) a_0b_0$

then this will not match  what the question is exactly asking?

Question is about  $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b) = \frac{(a,b)}{\gcd(a,b)}$

Comment: $$da_0b_0 = \frac{da_0db_0}{d}$$

Comment: oh thanks!! that thinking doesn't came in my mind @DanielFischer

Comment: ${\rm lcm}(a,b)\gcd(a,b) = ab\iff {\rm lcm}(a,b) = \dfrac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)} =  \dfrac{da_0(db_0)}{d} = da_0b_0\ $ so it suffices to prove the final equality $\,{\rm lcm}(a,b) = da_0b_0\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically this:$\DeclareMathOperator{\gcd}{\text{gcd}}$ $\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{\text{lcm}}$

Let $a, b~$ be as described in question. Consider $\gcd(a, b) = d$. Then by the definition of $\gcd$ we have that, $$ d|a ~\text{ and }~ d|b $$
Thus, we have that $a = dk_1$ and $b = dk_2$. Again, from the definition of $\lcm$ we have  $$ \lcm(a, b) = d \cdot k_1 \cdot k_2 $$
Hence:
$$ a \cdot b = d k_1 \cdot d k_2 = d \cdot (d \cdot k_1 \cdot k_2) = \gcd(a, b) \cdot \lcm(a, b) $$

Comment: It's a bit clearer by manipulating the original equation - see my comment on the answer.